# Assert Javascript value in C# with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, web-testing

I'm writing a test for a webapp. At one point in the application the webpage is completed using Javascript.
For testing I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with `NUnit` and `Selenium`.
I want to check if the box with `id=j_idt13:JNumber` has the text value of `sometext`.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
string valoare = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return $('#j_idt13\\:JNumber').val();");
Assert.IsTrue(valoare.Equals("sometext"));
```

I keep getting this error:

> "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo:JNumber".

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you have something that works but I'd like to caution you to avoid using JavaScript to fetch the value of the element, in fact in general it should be avoided when doing your tests except when there is no other way to do what you want to do. The reason is that Selenium is supposed to behave as a typical user would. Typical users don't type JavaScript into a page or interact with it directly. This goes extra for using jQuery as your tests should not assume that jQuery exists on the page and is functioning. Selenium itself provides the ability to fetch the values of fields so I'd recommend you rewrite your code to something like:

`driver.FindElement(By.Id("j_idt13:JNumber")).GetAttribute("value");`

Comment: I tried your example and it works great. I didn't want to use javascript, I never used GetAttribute before. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error I found something that works:

```
string valoare = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return document.getElementById('j_idt13\\:JNumber').value;");
```

Why it works, I don't know. Basically is the same command.
And jQuery is working with other commands, just not the one I tried first.

Comment: The huge problem is the ID naming scheme you've got going on is terrible. Are you the developer of the page? If not, please speak to them. I'm surprised anything works, especially since `:` has special meaning in not only jQuery, but a lot of different CSS frameworks.

Comment: Yes, I know its not a good naming scheme. Thank you for your comment.